# How to bind private key with certificate chain?

Tags: java, android, security, provider, pkcs#11

I'm implementing a PKCS#11 JCE provider for Android and there's a method from `java.security.KeyStoreSpi` which I don't understand:

[`public void engineSetKeyEntry(String name, Key key, char[] pin,
            Certificate[] certificateChain)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStoreSpi.html#engineSetKeyEntry%28java.lang.String,%20java.security.Key,%20char%5b%5d,%20java.security.cert.Certificate%5b%5d%29)

How can I bind private key with certificate chain? By CKA_ID attribute?

Comment: Side comment: are you aware that Oracle has its [own PKCS#11 provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/p11guide.html#P11Provider)?

Comment: @DuncanJones yes, Oracle has, but I'm doing it for Android.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to fully understand the question, but as far as I know, the PKCS#11 standard does not fully define how a Private Key / Public Key and a Certificate are linked all together. Rather, the standard (v3.01) does recommend to share the same CKA_ID between the 3 objects.
If you want to make a link between several obejct this is what I would also recommend. If we speak only about Asymetric keys, then you can find other means to link a public key to other related crypto materials (such as comparing the public Modulus for RSA world)